# Wildcard search on NSString or NSData

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for way to search through string.

For example, i do have string (just part of string)

> bob ala john mike mark jenny

and i need to locate this part in huge list of names by searching for example

> bob XXX john mike XXX jenny

treating "XXX" as wildcard for search

If possible, can it be done on `NSData` converting names to hex ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do such searches on a string using regular expressions.

For example with

```
NSString *string = …
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *pattern;
pattern = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:… 
                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                      error:&error];
[pattern enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:
^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
  // here you get a match 
}];
```

I'm not an expert in regular expressions, but this pattern should work: `@"bob .* john mike .* jenny"`

You cannot use regular expressions directly on instances of `NSData`, because these are text encoding agnostic and does not know anything about characters stored in.